# Monitoring django postgres connections

Tags: django, postgresql, connection-pooling

I am using django-postgrespool as a connection pooling backend for my application. I want to find out if it's working properly or not. How do I monitor the ongoing connections to postgres from django to find out if the connections are getting reused.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the [django-debug-toolbar.](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) Among many other options, you can monitor the queries to the database for each page and the response time.

This is a screenshot from the plugin documentation:
[image]